# Ansible - How loop over registered

Tags: ansible

I'm using the module stat for checking if some files exists in a remote server and registering their result in a variable. i.e. config files I'm looking for: conf_dev.conf, conf_pred.conf, conf_pro.conf.

Later I'm using the copy module for transfering only the files that are missing using a conditional based on an attribute stored in 
    variable.results.{{(ITEM)index}}.stat.exists. 
This returnsTRUE if file exists and FALSE if does not.

For running properly As the register variable is an array there are an index storing the result for each file I'm asking so I don't know how to convert the item in a index (0,1,2,3)

Does anyone know how to get the index of an item? I've tried this (look at the last line):

```
- name: Checking if common configuration files exists
  stat:
    path: "{{HOME_COMUN_CONFIG}}/{{item}}"
  with_items: "{{LIST_COMMON_CONFIGURATION_ARTIFACTS}}"
  register: store_results

- name: debug existe_app_comun
  debug:
    var: store_results

- name: Deploying missing files
  copy:
    src: "{{DIRTEMP_COMUN_CONFIG}}/{{item}}"
    dest: "{{HOME_COMUN_CONFIG}}/{{item}}"
  with_items: "{{LIST_COMMON_CONFIGURATION_ARTIFACTS}}"
  when: existe_app_comun.results.{{index(item)}}.stat.exists is defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you loop over `LIST_COMMON_CONFIGURATION_ARTIFACTS` if you want to loop over registered variable?

```
- name: Deploying missing files
  copy:
    src: "{{DIRTEMP_COMUN_CONFIG}}/{{ item.item }}"
    dest: "{{HOME_COMUN_CONFIG}}/{{ item.item }}"
  with_items: "{{ existe_app_comun.results }}"
  when: item.stat.exists
```

Here `item` is an element of results and `item.item` is an element of original loop.

P.S. if files at destination folder are not modified and should be same as in `DIRTEMP_COMUN_CONFIG`, then you must not use `stat`+`copy`, but just use `copy` – because it's idempotent and will not copy the same file twice.